# PyPi versioning

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, pypi

Newbie here. I've created my first Python package and I managed to register it on Pypi, as well as upload the tar.gz file. Now whenever I want to run:

```
pip install myPackage
```

I get this error in console:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement myPackage (from versions: 1.0dev)
No distributions matching the version for flashCardStudy
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/xxx/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I believe this is because my version is *development* version I guess? So yeah, I can install it by adding `--pre` argument but what I'd really like is to turn it into a *normal* version so to speak.

I've tried figuring out how to do it and looking at some docs but I can't still figure it out. In my `setup.py` my version is set to '1.0' so I don't see where to problem is. If anyone wants to have a look at the file, [here](https://gist.github.com/comatory/10ad9d5d425132e755c2) it is.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem. I used utility called Paster which generates package structure, including `setup.py` and `setup.cfg` files among others. My utility hasn't been updated in a while and meanwhile submission rules to PyPi have changed. It now requires certain `setup.py` structure and unless it passes via `pip`, it's labeled as development version - which pip does not install without `--pre` argument.

So I just went to PyPi pages and looked at `setup.py` tutorial, did it their way and now it works.